# Modify the version of the dependency in maven project, but the internal dependency version of the modified dependency remains unchanged

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

[img01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1MsH.png)
As shown in the above figure,When I do not modify the version of the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency which indicated by the arrow, the version of the internal dependency which in the red box is normal.Here is the pom.xml of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 2.6.11:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.11</version>
  <name>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</name>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

[img02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRCa0.png)
But the version of the internal dependency which in the red box remains unchanged when I modify the version of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency.Here is the pom.xml of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 3.0.1:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <name>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</name>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I expect that the internal dependency version can be modified to the version which in the dependencies tag of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 3.0.1 pom.xml  when I modify the version of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb from 2.6.11 to 3.0.1, not the version of the dependencies tag which in the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 2.6.11 pom.xml

Comment: This looks like an issue with IntelliJ. Maybe pressing the "refresh" button ("Reload All Maven Projects") on the left of the Maven panel already helps.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder, no, that is definitely not an IntelliJ issue, IntelliJ spawns dedicated RPC server in order to retrieve pom meta, so, in the most cases IntelliJ UI conforms with maven meta.

Comment: @dqxfz what you are observing is actually an expected behaviour: since you defined `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent pom, it imports all versions of dependencies from `spring-boot-dependencies` (and then from `spring-data-bom`) moreover, due to that, it overrides versions of transitive dependencies. The basic idea is following: you are either use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent pom or you are mature enough to not use it.

Comment: Okay，thank you, but I still want to know that there have been no changes to the internal version after my modifications，Is there a reason enough to convince me?

Comment: @dqxfz NO. spring/spring-boot projects distribute their developments for free with the only one essential restriction: you are either use those developments as is or you are the architect of your own fortunes - nobody will able to answer whether your modifications are correct or not.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Okay, I'm just curious about this phenomenon